# how to connect at mysql database in my vm machine with linux use c++

Tags: c++, mysql

I tried to find information on how to do this but my teacher told me ""you have a local ip and trying to ssh you shoot yourself in the knee with a sawed-off shotgun""

Comment: Connecting from the same machine should not be different from connecting from any machine with the exception of using 127.0.0.1 on the local which won't work on the remote. You should find information to connect to a mysql server for whatever library or method you are using.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

i used mysql.h which installed via vcpkg from it i used mysql_real_connect and mysql_query method

thx @drescherjm for advice

```
  if (mysql_real_connect(conn, "server adress", "root", "", "database", 0, NULL, 0) == NULL){ 
  printf("error");
}
```